KeyDown event needing multiple presses
I am trying to change some elements of my WPF page after pressing the right and left keys on my keyboard. It works somewhat fine, my problem is that I need to press the right or left keys 3 times each time I want something to change. Also, I don't know if it's relevant but a weird rectangle appears after pressing the key for the first time, but if I press it again it disappears.
XAML code
<Page x:Class="PokemonGroveGreen.Bag"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PokemonGroveGreen"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Bag">

    <Viewbox x:Name="mainViewbox" Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both" Focusable="True" KeyDown="Viewbox_KeyDown">
        <Grid>
            <!-- Background -->
            <Image Source="/Images/bagBackground.png"></Image>
            
            <!-- Pocket symbols -->
            <Grid Height="43" Width="338" Margin="25,348,621,347">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- Items -->
                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>
                
                <!-- Medicine -->
                <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>

                <!-- Poké Balls -->
                <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>

                <!-- TMs & HMs -->
                <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>
    
                <!-- Berries -->
                <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>

                <!-- Treasures -->
                <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>
                
                <!-- Battle Items -->
                <Border Grid.Column="6" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>
                
                <!-- Key Items -->
                <Border Grid.Column="7" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </Grid>
            
            <!-- Pocket text -->
            <TextBlock x:Name="pocketBlock" Text="Items" Height="50" Width="350" FontSize="40" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="18,413,616,275"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Page>

XAML.CS
namespace PokemonGroveGreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para Bag.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Bag : Page
    {
        Trainer trainer;

        public Bag(Trainer trainer)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainViewbox.Focus();

            this.trainer = trainer;
        }

        private void Viewbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                pocketBlock.Text = "DERECHA";
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                pocketBlock.Text = "IZQUIERDA";
            }
        }
    }
}

Screenshot of the rectangle:

I tried changing the event to the page, the grid and the viewbox. I also tried using the KeyDown event and the PreviewKeyDown event. Both worked the same way.

You've made the ViewBox "Focusable"; which is (probably) introducing additional "interaction behaviour". The (hidden) Grid may (also) be inheriting "focusability"; ergo, the dotted marque (and extra key strokes). You should rethink why you are adapting this pattern when a (radio) button may be more appropriate.
